# .NET Core - directory permissions Linux

Tags: c#, linux, unix, .net-core, directory-permissions

In my Unit Test project for .NET Core I'm trying to create a folder and then limit access permissions.

So far I implemented Windows version of this code:

```
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(DriveManager.LogicalDrive + ":\\testDir");
    DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = new DirectorySecurity(dirInfo.FullName, AccessControlSections.All);

    var securityId = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;

    FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(securityId, FileSystemRights.ListDirectory, AccessControlType.Deny);
    dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(rule);
    dirInfo.SetAccessControl(dirSecurity);
```

Obviously `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User` won't work on Unix type OS. 
I'm not sure whether other functions may be incompatible either.

Could you propose universal solution (for Windows and Unix type OS)?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Like you care read [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7325) `WindowsIdentity.*` API is only Windows Feature with no replacement on other systems (every method will throw PNSE). Temporary solution can be `scripts` section in `project.json` or self scripting because at this moment is now way to get this in clean .Net core on Linux and OSX